# how does onesignal and other push notification services work without json configuration file?

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

hey i'm interested in the way that we setup a notification service using onesignal, but i know if an application use firebase for sending notification, it needs a json configuration file.

Here's [a link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0)!

so how does onesignal android sdk initialize the application to recieve notification from fcm or gcm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json configuration file for Firebase is just to make your task easy. You can anytime initialize your Firebase App from code but that involves some coding. Android Studio is developed by Google, Firebase is developed by Google so better to make the things easy by including a google-services.json and one google-services plugin. As simple as that.

You can initialise Firebase with the following code:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setApiKey("<VAL>").
                setApplicationId("<VAL>").
                setDatabaseUrl("<VAL>").
                setGcmSenderId("<VAL>").
                setStorageBucket("<VAL>").build());
```

`FirebaseInitProvider` does the same task for you

Source: [Link](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/how-does-firebase-initialize-on-android.html)

Comment: thank you for your answer,so do you know any sample or reference to initialize it with code?

Comment: so how to find these parameters from firebase console?

Comment: You have to copy these parameters from the same google-services.json :P

Comment: so how does onesignal generates these IDs?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used OneSignal.